# Google Apps - How to get all files name from current directory?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-drive-api

How I can get all files name from current directory?

I have a code

```
function showAllFollderFronRoot() {

  // get all files from the ROOT folder
  var files = parentFolder;
  while (files.hasNext()) {
    var file = files.next();  
   //  Logger.log(file.getName());
   DocumentApp.getUi().alert(file.getName());
  }
}
```

But it work only with ROOT dir. 
How I can get all file names in array in current dir?

UPDATE:
I have a file structure: MT/MT.100-107/MT.100-1007.1001.doc
I need make code, if somebody open New Template from Docs - script need automatically safe this file with true structure - with next filename + 1 (example MT.100-1007.1002.doc, next new file from Template - MT.100-1007.1003.doc ...) 
Script need to find all filenames => show last bigger count (1002.doc) => count + 1 => save this file with new filename MT.100-1007.1003.doc

My code work, but it make tmp file in Root dir & not work perfect, because it not calculate last bigger count in current dir and if I delete file, example MT.100-1007.1003.doc in dir MT, and make new file in dir UA - count be MT.100-1007.1004.doc no matter what the names of the files are in the folder UA.

These script with mistakes, how I can fix it?

```
/**
 * @OnlyCurrentDoc
 */
function saveFilename() {

  // Get current file name
  const ui = DocumentApp.getUi(),
    doc = DocumentApp.getActiveDocument(), //Added
    thisFileId = doc.getId(),
    thisFileName = doc.getName();

  const thisFile = DriveApp.getFileById(thisFileId);//Modified from getFolderById
  const parentFolder = thisFile.getParents();
  const currentFolder = parentFolder.next();//Modified from currentFolderName
  const currentFolderName = currentFolder.getName();//Added
  //ui.alert(currentFolderName);

  /*Store a init file in root to getLatestFileNumber*/
  var initIter = DriveApp.getFilesByName(currentFolderName + 'init00'),
    initBool = initIter.hasNext(),
    init;


  if (!initBool) {
    init = DriveApp.createFile(currentFolderName + 'init000', '0');
  } else {
    init = initIter.next();
  }

  /*Get current Number and format it to 4 digits*/
  var currentNum = init.getBlob().getDataAsString() * 1 + 1,
    formatNum = ('0000' + currentNum).substr(-3);

  /*If filename already contains folderName, do nothing*/
  if (!(thisFileName.search(currentFolderName) + 1)) {
    doc.setName(currentFolderName +'.' + formatNum).saveAndClose();
    init.setContent(currentNum);
  }
  // delete TMP file from ROOT dir
  DriveApp.getFileById(init.getId()).setTrashed(true)
}
```

Comment: Use `currentFolder` instead of `DriveApp` when searching for files.

Answer (score 0):

- You want to retrieve filenames of all files in the parent folder of the active document.

If my understanding is correct, how about this answer?

#### Flow:

The flow of this script is as follows.

1. Retrieve file ID of the active document.
2. Retrieve parent folder ID of the active document.
3. Retrieve files in the parent folder ID.
4. Retrieve filenames of files.

#### Modified script:

```
function showAllFollderFronRoot() {
  var fileId = DocumentApp.getActiveDocument().getId();
  var parentFolderId = DriveApp.getFileById(fileId).getParents().next().getId();
  var files = DriveApp.getFolderById(parentFolderId).getFiles();
  while (files.hasNext()) {
    var file = files.next();
    Logger.log(file.getName())
  }
}
```

#### Note:

- This sample script supposes as follows.

  - The parent of the active document is only one.
  - All files in the parent folder of the active document are retrieved. But the folders are not retrieved.

#### References:

- [getId()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/document/document#getid)
- [getParents()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/file#getparents)
- [getFolderById(id)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/drive-app#getfolderbyidid)
- [getFiles()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/drive-app#getfiles)

If I misunderstand your question, please tell me. I would like to modify it.

Comment: @Oleksandr I'm really sorry I misunderstand what you want. But unfortunately, I cannot understand what you want from ``my problem in different`` and your question yet. So can I ask you about the detail information about what you want to do? I would like to solve your issue. I'm sorry for my poor English skill.

Comment: Thank you for references and your answer. But my problem in different:

1. I have dir structure (real example)
MT
  -- MT.100-107
    -- MT.100-107.1001.doc
    -- MT.100-107.1002.doc
....

Comment: I need to create a script that finds all the files in the current folder and automatically appends the next file to the new filename (MT.100-107.1003.doc, ...1004.doc, ...1005.doc).. 
But I can't work with google API last time, I have a full script, but it count only for all files, not in current directory, and have mistake.

Comment: @Oleksandr Thank you for replying and the additional information. But I cannot understand about the dir structure shown in your comment. I'm really sorry for my poor skill. And it seems that what you want to do from your comment is different from your initial question. So can you update your question? This is also useful for other users. About markdown, I'm sorry for the inconvenience. Markdown can also put the images and links. Is this information useful for you? https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help

Comment: Thank you for answer. 
My file structure: MT/MT.100-107/MT.100-107.1001.doc and filename consist from folder name + dot + 1000. Next filename = folder name + dot + 1001...
How I can list all filenames, then find filename with max number and plus 1 to filename?

Answer (score 0):

I fix this problem, but idk how to parse last 4 digits in filename and find MAX from it. Do you have any idea? method slice(4) not working in apps script :(

```
function currFiles() {

  const ui = DocumentApp.getUi(),
    doc = DocumentApp.getActiveDocument(),
    thisFileId = doc.getId(),
    thisFileName = doc.getName();

  const thisFile = DriveApp.getFileById(thisFileId);
  const parentFolder = thisFile.getParents();
  const currentFolder = parentFolder.next();
  const currentFolderName = currentFolder.getName();
  const currentFolderId = currentFolder.getId();

  // get all files in currentFolder

  var folderId = currentFolderId;
  // Log the name of every file in the folder.
  var files = DriveApp.getFolderById(folderId).getFiles();
  while (files.hasNext()) {
    var file = files.next();
    Logger.log(file.getName());
  }
}
```

Comment: Follow-up questions should be posted as new question not as part of an answer.